# React - Call function from 'sibling' component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Here's my current model, check it out, plz

```
import component 1 & 2 

export default class App extends Component {  
  render() {    
    return (

        <Component1/>       
        <Component2/>

    );
  }
}
```

Inside component 1, I have a function: pushData() after running this function, I want to execute next with fetchData() on component 2 but I can't find out way to reference to 2 from 1 because they're not parent-child?!

Comment: you can use the propriety boolean, when you will finish your fist operation, use setStatus react function to update the component tree and your second component can run the second function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done in a lot of ways, considering the code shared above has Class based implementation, I would suggest the following solution.

- First pass a function to the Component1, name it **dataPushed**.
- Second, create a state variable in the parent, name it **dataPushed**, initialize it to be false.
- Third pass a function and a state variable from parent to Component2, name it **dataFetched** and **fetchData** respectively.

Now Component1 will have it's own function to push the data, let's call this function **pushData**. As soon as the logic for pushing data is over, call the passed prop function **dataPushed**. This props will update the parent state with current status i.e. data is pushed and set the state variable to be true.

Now this state variable is passed to the Component2 already, using ComponentDidUpdate in Component 2. We can know the state of dataPush from component 1 and if it is true, you can call the Component2 internal function to fetch the data.

As soon as the data is fetched, call the prop passed to this Component2 to let the parent know that latest data has been fetched and set the parent state variable for dataPushed to be false.

Ignore the function and variable names used, feel free to use yours.

I have created a Sandbox with code,

https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-forest-5kc68?file=/src/App.js

I hope this solves your problem. 
Let me know if you are still stuck or unclear about any of the above explanation.

Comment: Your answer's almost perfect, I only customize little for reality mine, Component1 isn't 'inherit' directly from App, so at mid-class I will write <ChildForm dataPushed={this.props.checkDataPushed} />, beside that, at App class I removed line resetFetchData={this.resetFetchData} (I can't see resetFetchData() or it have potential meaning)... btw, I must remove parentheses from this.props.dataPushed; because React don't think it is function, currently app run smoothly, thanks everyone for support! regards!

Answer (score 2):

Architecturally what you're trying to do is not a good idea.

For example, if you change the component that has the function you want to use, you'll need to remember to update any dependencies that use this function. This becomes hard to maintain.

React props actually make it really easy to solve this problem using the [dependency injection pattern](https://www.sandimetz.com/blog/2009/03/21/solid-design-principles). If you're not familiar with dependency injection, it essentially means that the dependencies come from the top down, the component that needs these dependencies doesn't know where this dependency is and isn't going out to get them. It simply gets the dependency passed in.

Instead of trying to use the method that lives in the sibling component, you can bring the function one level up and have it live in a parent component. Same with the state.

Imagine this parent:

```
class Container extends React.Component {
  state = {
    counter: 0
  };

  reallyCoolFunction = () => {
    this.setState({ counter: this.state.counter + 1 });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Cool
          counter={this.state.counter}
          doCoolThing={this.reallyCoolFunction}
        />
        <Wannabe doCoolThing={this.reallyCoolFunction} />
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

The above `Container` component creates the function and passes it to both components. Each component would then call the function when needed, for example:

```
class Wannabe extends React.Component {
  handleClick = () => {
    this.props.doCoolThing();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Wannabe</h2>

        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>click</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Then the component that in your app owns the function gets the relevant props passed down:

```
class Cool extends React.Component {
  handleClick = () => {
    this.props.doCoolThing();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Cool</h2>

        <p>{this.props.counter}</p>

        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>click</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

If your app is growing and you're planning on working on it for a while, you may want to consider implementing a state management solution like [Redux](https://redux.js.org/). It makes state management easier.

If you were to use functional components instead of class components, a third option is available to you, and that's building your own custom hooks. If you're not yet familiar with hooks, that might be a bit of a learning curve. You can read the [React hooks documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html) on how to do that.

I have created a demo of the container component and child component example described. In this example they both have the ability to update state that is displayed in the `Cool` component: https://codesandbox.io/s/dry-hill-r425r?file=/src/App.js

---

Answer (score 1):

You've got to pass a callback from the parent which will be called after your first function is executed, update parent's state and then pass a prop to the second component in order to inform it.

```js
import React from "react";

class Component1 extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    // execute your first function here

    if (this.props.onPushData) {
      this.props.onPushData();
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <p>Component1</p>;
  }
}

class Component2 extends React.Component {
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.dataPushed !== this.props.dataPushed) {
      if (this.props.dataPushed) {
        // execute your second function here
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <p>Component2</p>;
  }
}

export default class extends React.Component {
  state = {
    dataPushed: false
  }

  handleDataPush = () => {
    this.setState({ dataPushed: true })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Component1 onPushData={this.handleDataPush} />
        <Component2 dataPushed={this.state.dataPushed} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here's an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/misty-glitter-lc18o?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 1):

One way to access component2's function in component1 is to use `refs` .

[Working demo is here.](https://codesandbox.io/s/access-2ztt1?file=/src/App.js)

**Code Snippet:**

```js
export default class App extends React.Component {
  ref = React.createRef();
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <Component1 comp2Ref={this.ref} />
        <Component2 ref={this.ref} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// Component1.js
export default class Component1 extends React.Component {
  pushData = () => {
    // make the first api call..
    console.log("comp 1 fun");
    // now call component2 function
    console.log(this.props);
    this.props.comp2Ref.current.fetchData();
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>component 1</h1>
        <button onClick={this.pushData}>push data button</button>.
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// Component2.js
export default class Component2 extends React.Component {
  fetchData = () => {
    console.log("comp 2 fun");
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>component 2</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Best way is to handle your scenario is to lift the `fetchData` function up to the parent and pass it as prop to the `component2`.

**Like this**

```js
export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: []
  };

  fetchData = () => {
    // fetch the data and update the state(data) and pass it as prosp in component 2
    console.log("comp 2 fun");
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <Component1 fetchData={this.fetchData} />
        <Component2 data={this.state.data} fetchData={this.fetchData} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// Component 1 pushData function

...
 pushData = () => {
    // make the first api call..
    console.log("comp 1 fun");
    // now call component2 function
    console.log(this.props);
    this.props.fetchData();
  };
...
```

Answer (score 1):

In the long term, I would recommend you to add **Redux** to the current stack, react has a limitation to scale with big hierarchy components and integration with backend API.

So if you are looking for a real project in the production, it is time to switch to **React-Redux**